# nodejs json.stringify a 1gb object running out of memory

Tags: json, node.js

I'm trying to json.stringify a 1 gb object so that I can write it to disk. I get `FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory`

What can I do to stringify successfully?

Comment: You might consider https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stringify bit by bit manually: if `y` is a key of `x`, then `JSON.stringify(y) + ":" + JSON.stringify(x[y])` gives you one segment.

Using `fs.appendFileSync`, for example, you can use:

```
var output = "out.json";
fs.writeFileSync(output, "{");
var first = true;
for(var y in x) {
    if(x.hasOwnProperty(y)) {
        if(first) first = false;
        else fs.appendFileSync(output, ",");
        fs.appendFileSync(output, JSON.stringify(y) + ":" + JSON.stringify(x[y]))
    }
} 
fs.appendFileSync(output, "}");
```

You can also use a [Write Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

Answer (score 0):

Extended with Object, Array checker

```
var first, y, i$, ref$, len$, toString$ = {}.toString;
switch (toString$.call(x).slice(8, -1)) {
case 'Object':
  fs.writeFileSync(output, '{');
  first = true;
  for (y in x) {
    if (x.hasOwnProperty(y)) {
      if (first) {
        first = false;
      } else {
        fs.appendFileSync(output, ',');
      }
      fs.appendFileSync(output, JSON.stringify(y) + ':' + JSON.stringify(x[y]));
    }
  }
  fs.appendFileSync(output, '}');
  break;
case 'Array':
  fs.writeFileSync(output, '[');
  first = true;
  for (i$ = 0, len$ = (ref$ = x).length; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
    y = ref$[i$];
    if (first) {
      first = false;
    } else {
      fs.appendFileSync(output, ',');
    }
    fs.appendFileSync(output, JSON.stringify(y));
  }
  fs.appendFileSync(output, ']');
  break;
default:
  fs.writeFileSync(output, JSON.stringify(x));
}
```